# OpenCV: correspondence between keypoints and descriptors

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, openmp, sift

I'm trying to parallelize OpenCV SIFT implementation with OpenMP (hurray! for me).

**First of all:** seriously? OpenCV doesn't offer any parallel implementation of the best detector/descriptor available today? Only SURF has a TBB and GPU implementations.

Anyway: what I want to know is if we compute

```
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
Mat descriptors;
detectAndCompute(image, mask, keypoints, descriptors, useProvided); //don't look mask and useProvided
```

It means that the descriptor relative to the `i-th` keypoint, i.e. `keypoints[i]`, is the `i-th` descriptor, i.e. `descriptors[i]`?

This is important because if that's a case, in such a parallel application I have to guarantee the order which `descriptors` is populated (so the correspondence between `keypoints` and `descriptors` is respected).

Comment: yes, indices are the same.

Comment: This is actually an answer. Post it, and I'll chose it ;)